# Expanding array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Supposing I have this array:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Foo",
        quantity: 2
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Bar",
        quantity: 3
    },
]
```

I want to expand/multiply the array elements depending on the value of `quantity` property. The desired output is this:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Foo"
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Foo"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Bar"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Bar"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Bar"
    }
]
```

Can I achieve that result without using a loop (for, foreach, etc..)? Can it be done using the built-in methods of the `Array` object?

**Edit**:

For anyone might need it, here is my solution using a loop.

```
const arrayOfObjects = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Foo",
        quantity: 2
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Bar",
        quantity: 3
    },
];
let result = [];

arrayOfObjects.forEach(element => {
    for (let i = 0; i < element.quantity; i++) {
        const {
            quantity,
            ...newElement
        } = element;

        result.push(newElement);
    }
});
```

Comment: Many things are possible in programming. Often the first step is to write some code. No, it's not possible to do a repetitive task like this without using a loop of some kind (unless you hard-code the indicies and write very WET code)

Comment: I am well  aware that I can achieve that through looping, what I was asking if there is a more efficient way to do it like using map or filter. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `for` loops are already much more efficient than array methods like `.map` and `.filter`.

Comment: That was helpful, I'll just use a loop. Thanks.

Comment: Then answer your own question so we can close this question

Comment: Sorry for the late posting of the answer, the question was on hold and I do not have the time to revisit this question until this afternoon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my own solution using a loop, as it was stated in the comments that using the built-in methods of the `Array` object is not as efficient as using a simple loop.

```
const arrayOfObjects = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Foo",
        quantity: 2
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Bar",
        quantity: 3
    },
];
let result = [];

arrayOfObjects.forEach(element => {
    for (let i = 0; i < element.quantity; i++) {
        const {
            quantity,
            ...newElement
        } = element;

        result.push(newElement);
    }
});
```